# Screenshot application to clipboard

Tags: java, javafx

In Windows, when you press prtscn it captures the whole screen, alt+prtscrn captures just the focused application.  Is this strictly controlled by the OS? I'm trying to determine if it's possible to override the part of the app that's captured to the clipboard.  I'm using an undecorated scene and thus supply my own dropshadow to the window. Screenshotting the app also captures the shadow and that's what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: There is method [snapshot()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) in class `javafx.scene.Node`. I found similar questions on _Stack Overflow_, including [how snapshot the entire scene in javafx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32708250/how-snapshot-the-entire-scene-in-javafx). Simply search for **javafx snapshot**.

Comment: @Abra The question is not about creating an image from a node, but about modifying the behaviour of `Alt + Printscreen`.

Comment: I'm wondering if I simply listen for that key combination in my app and copy my own image into the clipboard, if that might overwrite what windows would normally capture.  I'll give that a shot and report back if it works.